# How to get JSON string into JavaScript from responsetext

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

so I've tried this for the entire day but can't seem to solve it.. I have some AJAX getting a JSON string from a PHP script, and now I want to get it into JavaScript.

What I've tried is this:

```
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);

    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","back.php?q="+query,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

But all I get is

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < x.extend.parseJSON xmlhttp.onreadystatechange

I've tried all type of code like

```
obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
alert(obj.length);
```

Whatever I do I basically get the error above.. don't know what to do.. I really wanna solve this with jQuery/JS..

Thanks alot for any help!

Comment: Most likely you're not receiving valid JSON.

Comment: Do a `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)` before. I suspect you're not getting JSON.

Comment: Why are you using a raw XMLHttpRequest ***and*** jQuery?!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: bfavaretto is right...if you're already including jquery you might as well use it's ajax methods...http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jquery you can just:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "back.php?q="+query,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response.length);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right, and to answer bfavaretto, due to lack of experience, won't do it now :)

Answer (score 0):

simply do...

```
url='your/url/to/the/file.php';
$.getJSON(url,
        function(data){
          alert(data);
          });
        });
```

Comment: This will likely fail for the same reason.